# Update table with 2 loops

Tags: sql, loops, subquery, sql-server-2016

I have to update 'End_A' in the table TSW. (SQL Server 2016)

1. Outer loop --> Select Start_a, C_ID from dbo.tsw group by TypeC order by start_A desc.

   In the outer loop I select the first record set Start_A (is not null)
2. Inner loop --> Select Up_Date from dbo.tsw group by TypeC where CA = 'whatever'
   and (update > Start_A) group by TypeC order by Up_Date desc.

   In the inner loop I search the corresponding record set (group by TypeC) to 
   update End_A.
   It is the next recordset Up_Date > Start_a with the condition ...
3. Select c_ID from outer lopp and update End_A with Up_date from inner loop
   Update End_A with selected Up_Date from inner loop.
4. Select the next corresponding record set (group by TypeC) to update End_A,
   till end of group by TypeC.
5. Select the next record set from outer loop, then step 2....

Always group by TypeC. TypeC is the 'block' to update multiple End_A.

This is the table (example) bevor update:

```
C_ID|TypeC| CA  |   Up_Date         |   Start_A | End_A |
----------------------------------------------------------------
14  |123  | AA  |2019-01-05 02:15:00|2019-01-03 |      |
24  |678  | AA  |2019-02-05 08:00:05|           |      |
12  |123  | AA  |2019-01-07 03:27:12|           |      |
19  |123  | BB  |2019-03-05         |2019-05-17 |      |
10  |456  | BB  |2019-11-05         |2019-10-01 |      |
23  |123  | BB  |2019-07-05         |           |      |
8   |123  | BB  |2019-01-05         |2019-02-01 |      |
7   |678  | BB  |2019-01-05         |2020-08-09 |      |
1   |678  | BB  |2019-01-05         |           |      |
2   |678  | CC  |2020-09-05         |2019-10-14 |      |
29  |678  | AA  |2020-01-05         |2020-01-05 |      |
15  |123  | CC  |2019-06-05         |           |      |
17  |678  | CC  |2022-01-05         |           |      |
55  |123  | CC  |2019-09-05         |           |      |
77  |678  | CC  |2019-01-05         |           |      |
47  |678  | AA  |2019-01-05         |           |      |
110 |456  | BC  |2019-11-05         |           |      |
```

> ```
>     Start Loop_1
>     select TSW.Start where start_A is not null 
>     from TSW
>     group by TypeC
>
>       Start Loop_2 --(Up_Date next emyty End_A with 'Up_Date')
>           Update TSW.End_a = Loop_2_End_A
>           select Up_Date
>           from
>           where TSW.Start_A is not null 
>               and "Loop_1 TypeC" = "Loop_2 TypeC"
>               and CA = "blabla" as Loop_2_End_A
>               order by up_date
>           group by TypeC
>
>           then select next relevant Up_Date from Loop_2
>       end loop2
>
>     select next from Loop_1
>     end loop_1
> ```

1. C_ID 14--> from next TypeC '123' where CA <> 'AA'(C_ID = 19)
2. C_ID 19 -->from next TypeC '123' where CA <> 'BB'(C_ID = 15)
3. C_ID 10 --> from next TypeC '456' where CA <> 'BB'(C_ID =110)
4. C_ID 8 --> from next TypeC '123' where CA <> 'BB'(C_ID = 15)
5. C_ID 7 --> from next TypeC '678' where CA <> 'BB'(C_ID = 17)

This is the table after update:

```
C_ID|TypeC| CA  |   Up_Date         |   Start_A | End_A    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
14  |123  | AA  |2019-01-05 02:15:00|2019-01-03 |2019-03-05|
24  |678  | AA  |2019-02-05 08:00:05|           |          |
12  |123  | AA  |2019-01-07 03:27:12|           |          |
19  |123  | BB  |2019-03-05         |2019-05-17 |2019-06-05|
10  |456  | BB  |2019-11-05         |2019-10-01 |2019-11-05|
23  |123  | BB  |2019-07-05         |           |          |
8   |123  | XX  |2019-01-05         |2019-02-01 |2019-06-05|
7   |678  | BB  |2019-01-05         |2020-08-09 |2020-09-05|
1   |678  | BB  |2019-01-05         |           |          |
2   |678  | CC  |2020-09-05         |2019-10-14 |2021-05-01|
29  |678  | AA  |2020-01-05         |2020-01-05 |2022-01-05|
15  |123  | CC  |2019-06-05         |           |          |
17  |678  | CC  |2022-01-05         |           |          |
55  |123  | CC  |2019-09-05         |           |          |
77  |678  | CC  |2019-01-05         |           |          |
47  |678  | AA  |2019-01-05         |           |          |
110 |456  | BC  |2019-11-05         |           |          |
```

How can I update in SQL the table with this selected informations in the innner loop?
Thanks in advance.

[image: NEw Table]

Comment: Explain the logic for `End_A`

Comment: End_A ist the next Date after value(Start_a) in the column Up_date 
group by TypeC order by Up_date

Comment: sorry still not clear. please explain each result on your desire data and how is calculated

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I use sql-server 2016 and have edit and add some information in my question.

Comment: where `2021-05-01` came from

Comment: For `ID = 14` why next date is `ID = 19` and not `ID = 8` ??

Comment: 2021-05-01 came from next record where CA <> 'CC'    
For ID=14 next date is ID=19 because TypeC = '123' and CA ='BB'  
I serach always the next record sort by Up_date.

Comment: But you dont have `2021-05-01`. And `ID 8 - TypeC 123 - 2019-01-05`  came before than `ID 19 - TypeC 123 - 2019-03-05`

Comment: I have added a new table. I hope it is now better to understand.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion?